# Estimate effect on mean of dependent variable of an increase in the independent variable in a linear regression

Tags: regression, estimation

Suppose I have the linear regression equation:

Y = B0 + B1(x)

How do I find the estimated effect on mean Y of an additional 50 to x?

I believe this is the multiplicative effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is obvious: if you have an equation `y = b0 + b1x` and `x` increased by 50, then `y' = b0 + b1(x + 50)`.

So `y' - y = b1 * 50`